# Eyedropper tool doesn't pick colors from locked layers in Flash CC 2014

Tags: adobe-flash

I just got Flash CC 2014. The first issue I noticed is that the Eyedropper tool does not pick a colour from a layer that is locked. This is different from Flash CS6, and I find it really pointless.

Is there a way to change it back to the old behavior? And if not, is there a reasonable way to pick colors without unlocking layers?